# scrivener_html paginate with query params in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

https://github.com/mgwidmann/scrivener_html
I am using scrivener paginate in elixir project.

I am showing list organisations in index with search query

http://localhost:4000/organizations?_utf8=%E2%9C%93&name=&address=&city=&state=CA&post=&web=&type=&contact=

When I am click next page, the query params or missing, getting like the below url.
http://localhost:4000/organizations?page=2

What I am expecting like this below:

http://localhost:4000/organizations?page=2&_utf8=%E2%9C%93&name=&address=&city=&state=CA&post=&web=&type=&contact=

The Pagination code is

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
      <%= pagination_links @organizations, previous: ~E(<i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>), next: ~E(<i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>)  %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass the rest of the [URL query parameters](https://github.com/mgwidmann/scrivener_html#query-string-parameters) to `scrivener`:

```
<%= pagination_links @conn, @organizations, @conn.params, ...  %>
```

Comment: @bala15 _what_ argument error? Please show the full message.